# Laravel orderBy but with specific row first

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table of categories in which I want to order by the description, but there is a specific one, id=19, which I want to go first.

I've tried

```
Category::orderByRaw('IF(category_id = 19, 0,1)')->orderBy('description')->get();
```

But get:

> BadMethodCallException: Call to undefined method
>   Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::orderByRaw()

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
Category::orderByRaw('IF(category_id = 19, 0,1)')->orderBy('description','asc')->get();
```

Order is necessary there in orderBy column,